# Operator does not work in test_that function

Tags: r, operators, testthat

I am trying to write a test_that function in R where I test if the dimensions of a data frame is either equal to one of two combinations of rows and columns using the "||" operator. But, it is returning the error that the "types are not compatible: integer is not logical." Is it even possible to use an "||" operator in an expect_equal()?

See below for example code.

```
test_that('data frame has correct number of rows and columns'){
expect_equal(dim(data_frame), c(60, 2) || dim(data_frame), c(60,1))
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `numeric` and logical operators like `||` are not a clear choice for using together; while `==0 ~ FALSE` and `!=0 ~ TRUE` (try `if (-1) 1 else 2` and same with `(0)`), I wouldn't rely on that.
2. You're mixing functionality. `expect_equal` takes two arguments and either passes or fails. For this, you are passing `dim(data_frame)` as the first argument and while you intend `c(60,2)` to be the second argument, your second argument is being *parsed* as `c(60, 2) || dim(data_frame)`, which is wrong for a couple of reasons, namely that `||` is not vectorized, it must compare length-1 with length-1. And you're sending a third argument, `c(60,1)`, which is being passed directly to the underlying call to `compare` ... but it isn't being used as a comparison value.

   What I'm inferring is that you expect `dim(data_frame) same as c(60,2)` or (`dim(data_frame) same as c(60,1)`, but your choice of syntax is not legal for R at all, much less in `expect_equal`.

I suggest as an alternative:

```r
expect_true(identical(dim(data_frame), c(60L,2L)) ||
              identical(dim(data_frame), c(60L,1L)))
```

Yet another way, with two tests:

```r
expect_equal(nrow(data_frame), 60L)
expect_true(ncol(data_frame) %in% 1:2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Your alternative only works if the first condition `c(60, 2)` is satisfied. If I make the data frame have the second dimensions `c(60,1)`, the test fails.

Comment: Right ... that's one of the problems with `all.equal` I had forgotten about ... ugh. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

seems like `expect_true(c(dim(data_frame), c(60, 2)) || c(dim(data_frame), c(60,1)))` worked!

Comment: Nope, try `expect_true(c(dim(data_frame), c(60, 9)) || c(dim(data_frame), c(60, 9))) `